# Agm-marker double click event

Tags: angular, angular6

How can i use a `dblClick` event on an agm-marker element (not agm-maps)?

The official documentation says that agm-marker only has a single click event, any thoughts?

Comment: Hello!  Could you give us a sanitized sample of the code you're working with?  That will help the Stack Overflow community to advise you.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up creating my own custom marker element, based off the old school non angular style `google.maps.Marker`, however I wrapped it in my own component.  Then from there I was able to add anything I wanted, which included the `dblclick` event.  It's a ton of work, however, once you're done, you can pretty much do what you want.
[here is the old school google.maps.Marker reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker) which you'll probably find useful if you're going to build this out.